# PHP Mail BCC To Multiple Recipients

Tags: php, email

I am trying to send email to multiple users through BCC fetching email id's from database, For this I have written Below code

```
$q = $db->query("SELECT group_concat(concat(''',user_email,''')) FROM topic_subscribe");
$recipients = array($q['user_email']);
$headers .= 'BCC: '. implode(",", $recipients) . "\r\n";
$a = mail( null, $subject, $message, $headers );
```

But it is not sending any email If I take `$recipients` manually like below it works

```
$recipients = array("jobs3433@gmail.com","foxhitz@gmail.com",);
```

may be fetching email id's from database is the problem but can not figure out the problem. any help pls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't concatenate quotes to `user_email`. And you need to give an alias to the `group_concat()` expression so you can refer to it by name in the returned value.

Then use `explode()` to split the value at the commas. But if you're just going to call `implode()`, you could just use the row value as it is.

```
$q = $db->query("SELECT group_concat(user_email) AS emails FROM topic_subscribe");
$headers .= 'BCC: '. implode(",", $q['emails']) . "\r\n";
$a = mail( null, $subject, $message, $headers );
```

Comment: Tried but not completing the process

Comment: showing output 'null if use query but when using 'fetchRow' instead 'query' it is outputting 'string(74) "mymailid1@gmail.com,mymailid2@gmail.com,mymailid3@gmail.com,mymail@gmail.com"'

Comment: `$db->query()` is not a standard PHP method. It sounds like it returns all the rows, not just a single row as you're using it. So you need `$q[0]['emails']`

Comment: it works using this  $q = $db->fetchRow("SELECT group_concat(user_email) AS emails FROM topic_subscribe");  '$headers .= 'BCC: '. $q['emails'] . "\r\n";' thanks